# PHP filter_input() and bindValue()

Tags: php, sql, crud

I am writing a basic CRUD application to get my head around `PHP`. I am a little confused as to what exactly the following code is doing. I understand the general concept of it but I am not 100% sure of the logic going on.

I am hoping someone might be able to help me understand it a bit better?

This is my script

```
    <?php
//Establish connection to db
require_once 'includes/db.php';

//Array for validation
$errors = array();

//Sanitize the fields to ensure db integrity.
$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$release_date = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'release_date', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$publisher = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'publisher', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$system = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'system', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$rating = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rating', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$num_players = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'num_players', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //Validate the form
    if(empty($title)){
        $errors['title'] = true;
    }
    if(empty($release_date)){
        $errors['release_date'] = true;
    }
    if(empty($publisher)){
        $errors['publisher'] = true;
    }
    if(empty($system)){
        $errors['system'] = true;
    }
    if(empty($rating)){
        $errors['rating'] = true;
    }
    if(empty($num_players)){
        $errors['num_players'] = true;
    }

    //If no errors
    if(empty($errors)){
        //Build SQL Statement
        $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO videogames SET title = :title, release_date = :release_date, publisher = :publisher, system = :system, rating = :rating, num_players = :num_players");
        //Bind values
        $sql -> bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql -> bindValue(':release_date', $release_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql -> bindValue(':publisher', $publisher, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql -> bindValue(':system', $system, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql -> bindValue(':rating', $rating, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql -> bindValue(':num_players', $num_players, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        //Execute SQL
        $sql -> execute();

        //Redirect back to homepage
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

I am a little confused as to what this line of code is doing:

```
$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Is it assigning the value in the input field of the form to the `$title` variable?

Also this line:

```
        $sql -> bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I read in the documentation that this

> Binds a value to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in
>   the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement.

If I am storing the data already in the `$title` variable then is there another way to prepare my `SQL` statement?

I'd appreciate any help, as I am trying to expand my knowledge of PHP. Many thanks!

Comment: "//Sanitize the fields to ensure db integrity." --- `filter_input` has nothing to do with db integrity

Comment: "I am a little confused as to what this line of code is doing:" --- what if you read some manual http://php.net/filter_input ? (it actually makes sense to read it *before* you ask a question)

Comment: "is there another way to prepare my SQL statement?" --- is anything wrong with the current code? Statements are only prepared with `prepare()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1 - filter_input

> I am a little confused as to what this line of code is doing:
>
> `$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`
>
> Is it assigning the value in the input field of the form to the $title variable?

Yes.

[`filter_input` was introduced in PHP 5](http://php.net/filter_input). What this  line of code is doing is grabbing the input variable (`$_POST['title']`), and then applying a [`SANITIZE` method](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) on it, that is; "*Strip tags, optionally strip or encode special characters*."

#### Question 2 - bindValue

> Also this line:
>
> `$sql -> bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);`
>
> If I am storing the data already in the $title variable then is there another way to prepare my SQL statement?

I don't actually understand this question, however I'll try my best.

This is a [`PDO` method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) to bind a value to a prepared query. Effectively, it does this:

- Hey MySQL, here's a query I need you to run

  - Query these tables
  - Get these columns back
- *MySQL does this*
- Hey MySQL, remember that query I asked you to run? Here's the values to filter the result set

You can read more about preparing and binding here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters

Another way in which you could `prepare` the query is the use of [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli), but the logic is the same.

---

<sup>This question was asked a year ago. I didn't revive it, OP edited his question and it was bumped. I see nothing wrong answering a question if OP still shows interest in an answer (by bumping) no matter the age of the question</sup>